# Is there a way to only colour part of a bottom border in QT without QPainter?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5, pyside

I can change the top, left, right and bottom of borders using the setStyleSheet funcion:

```
self.button1.setStyleSheet("""border-bottom: 1px solid #654321; border-top: 1px solid #123456""")
```

and this creates a button like so:

[image]

However is it possible to create borders like the one below using qss stylesheets:

[image]

Where the bottom border in only not starting at the very edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is possible, but only whenever the following aspects are respected and considered:

- both vertical borders are *always* explicitly hidden (`border-left` and `border-right` are set to `none`);
- the [`border radius`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#border-radius-prop) is only specified for the bottom corners, and it only sets the horizontal radius, while leaving the vertical one to 0;
- this is a "*hack*" that specifically uses geometry aspects and only works if the above  are respected;

```py
    bottomMargin = 24
    self.button1.setStyleSheet("""
        QAbstractButton {{
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-left: none;
            border-right: none;
            border-bottom-left-radius: {margin}px 0;
            border-bottom-right-radius: {margin}px 0;
        }}
    """.format(margin=bottomMargin)
```

Comment: Why are you using QAbstractButton instead of QToolButton or QPushButton, would it be fair to assume that I could do this for the top and bottom but also the left and right ones but I could not do this at the same time for all four parts?

Comment: @NejoFS I didn't know what type of button you used, so using QAbstractButton was the safest choice that would have worked for any button. Yes, exactly, as noted in the "requirements" list, this can only work with side edges that are next to invisible borders. If you want to draw "cut out" angles, then you'd be better with custom drawing in QPainter.

Comment: Thank you, so I can only do it for the top and bottom or the left side and right side. Thank you.